# RTNETLINK answers: File exists ubuntu server 12.04

Tags: networking

I am using Ubuntu 12.04, running in VMWare. My `/etc/network/interfaces` file consists of:

```
# The loopback network interface  
    auto lo  
    iface lo inet loopback  

# The loopback network interface  
    auto lo  
    iface lo inet loopback  


# The primary network interface  
    auto eth0 
    iface eth0 inet static  
    address 192.168.3.15
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 192.168.3.0  
    broadcast 192.168.3.255
    gateway 192.168.3.254
    dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 

    auto eth1
    iface eth1 inet static  
    address 192.168.3.40
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 192.168.3.0  
    broadcast 192.168.3.255
    gateway 192.168.3.15
    dns-nameservers 192.168.1.15
```

I ran the command `/etc/init.d/networking restart` which returned this:

```
*Running /etc/init.d/networking restart is deprecated because it may not enable again some interfaces  
*Reconfiguring network interfaces...  
 RTNETLINK answers: File exists  
 Failed to bring up eth1
 [ OK ]
```

Comment: What is the result of: sudo ifdown eth1 && sudo ifup -v eth1?

Comment: Proper command is `sudo service networking restart`

Comment: root@ubuntu:/home/sare# sudo ifdown eth1 && sudo ifup -v eth1
Configuring interface eth1=eth1 (inet)
run-parts --verbose /etc/network/if-pre-up.d
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/wireless-tools
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/wpasupplicant
ip addr add 192.168.3.40/255.255.255.0 broadcast +        dev eth1 label eth1
ip link set dev eth1   up